# What is an effective way to trigger high memory consumption in an app?

Tags: java, android, memory

I want to make my app use up a lot of memory to experiment with onTrimMemory and garbage collection. What would be an easy way to do this?

Comment: Just create a map/list and keep adding strings to it in a big loop. Eventually, you will run out of memory depending on loop size.